# Street names & markers far too small

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart

I have created a Google map using Dart and am currently in the process of adding markers. However the street names are so small its nearly impossible to read them and when zooming in to the map the size decreases further as shown here:[image: Google map tiny street names]

This problem also affects the zoom controls in the top left as well as the marker that is barely visible. Is there any way to increase the size of these?

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in? Try Ctrl + 0 or Cmd + 0 to reset it.

Comment: Yep you solved it thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you're zoomed in on the browser. `Ctrl + 0` (Win/Linux) or `Cmd + 0` (Mac) usually fixes this in all modern browsers. Google usually keeps sizes relatively standard.